# Pandas Use Loop to compare datetime in each row with all rows and saving subset of results

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, for-loop, filter

This is my first time using Python (I've used R before), so please bear with me on this question. Basically, I'd like to use a for loop to compare the `datetime` value in each row with all other `datetime` values in the other rows in a pandas `pd` dataframe, and if the time difference is 4 hours or less store these rows into a subset object `df` for later processing. However, I'm unsure with where to begin with this.

Let's assume that this is my dataset:

```
              Origin           Destination                Time
0           New York                 Cairo 2016-03-28 02:00:00
1           New York           Los Angeles 2016-03-28 04:00:00
2             Boston                Hawaii 2016-03-28 06:00:00
3           New York                Boston 2016-03-28 08:00:00
4        Los Angeles                Boston 2016-03-28 10:00:00
5        Los Angeles                Hawaii 2016-03-28 12:00:00
```

This is what the result should look like:

```
>>>df[0]
              Origin           Destination                Time
0           New York                 Cairo 2016-03-28 02:00:00
>>>df[1]
              Origin           Destination                Time
0           New York                 Cairo 2016-03-28 02:00:00
1           New York           Los Angeles 2016-03-28 04:00:00
>>>df[2]
              Origin           Destination                Time
0           New York                 Cairo 2016-03-28 02:00:00
1           New York           Los Angeles 2016-03-28 04:00:00
2             Boston                Hawaii 2016-03-28 06:00:00
>>>df[3]
1           New York           Los Angeles 2016-03-28 04:00:00
2             Boston                Hawaii 2016-03-28 06:00:00
3           New York                Boston 2016-03-28 08:00:00
>>>df[5]
              Origin           Destination                Time
3           New York                Boston 2016-03-28 08:00:00
4        Los Angeles                Boston 2016-03-28 10:00:00
5        Los Angeles                Hawaii 2016-03-28 12:00:00
```

I don't understand how to get this.

Comment: *4 hours or less store these rows*...four hours less compared to what specific metric? Any row? You might not subset anything!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a pure pandas solution without any loops, you can do it like this:

1. Do a cross-join of the data with itself
2. Select rows where the difference between times is < 4 hours
3. Group the data

Here is an example:

```
# Load file
data = pd.read_csv("abc.csv", delimiter="\t")
data["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Time"], infer_datetime_format=True)
data["Ignore"] = 1
data = data.reset_index()

# cross-join
merged = pd.merge(data, data, how="outer", on="Ignore")

# this is the magic
merged = merged[(merged["Time_x"] - merged["Time_y"]).abs() < pd.Timedelta("4 hours")]

# so you have some structure
groups = merged.groupby("index_x").apply(lambda x : x.set_index("index_y")[["Origin_y", "Destination_y", "Time_y"]])
```

This gives you a result like this:

```
        Origin_y    Destination_y   Time_y
index_x index_y         
0   0   New York    Cairo   2016-03-28 02:00:00
    1   New York    Los Angeles 2016-03-28 04:00:00
1   0   New York    Cairo   2016-03-28 02:00:00
    1   New York    Los Angeles 2016-03-28 04:00:00
    2   Boston  Hawaii  2016-03-28 06:00:00
2   1   New York    Los Angeles 2016-03-28 04:00:00
    2   Boston  Hawaii  2016-03-28 06:00:00
    3   New York    Boston  2016-03-28 08:00:00
3   2   Boston  Hawaii  2016-03-28 06:00:00
    3   New York    Boston  2016-03-28 08:00:00
...
```

And you can access individual rows like this:

```
> groups.T[0].T

Origin_y    Destination_y   Time_y
index_y         
0   New York    Cairo   2016-03-28 02:00:00
1   New York    Los Angeles 2016-03-28 04:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was wondering if there's a way for me to find out how many subset groups were created with this function, and whether each row's subset group is different from each other.

Comment: There is exactly one subset for each original row. The k'th subset contains all entry that are within 4 hours of the k'th entry.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with This:

```
                Origin              Destination                  Time
0             New York                    Cairo   2016-03-28 00:00:00
1             New York               Los Angeles  2016-03-28 02:00:00
2               Boston                    Hawaii  2016-03-28 04:00:00
3             New York                   Boston   2016-03-28 06:00:00
4          Los Angeles                   Boston   2016-03-28 08:00:00
5          Los Angeles                  Hawaii    2016-03-28 10:00:00
```

Use a dict to store your DataFrames and then access the Dict with Index of 
dataFrame.

```
NewDict = {} 
for i, e in df.iterrows():
    NewDict[i] = df[ (df['Time'] > e['Time']-pd.Timedelta('4 hours')) & (df['Time'] < e['Time'] + pd.Timedelta('4 hours'))]

NewDict[0]

                Origin             Destination                  Time
0             New York                   Cairo   2016-03-28 00:00:00
1             New York              Los Angeles  2016-03-28 02:00:00

NewDict[4]
                Origin              Destination                  Time
3             New York                   Boston   2016-03-28 06:00:00
4          Los Angeles                   Boston   2016-03-28 08:00:00
5          Los Angeles                  Hawaii    2016-03-28 10:00:00
```

To get counts:

```
for k, v in NewDict.iteritems():
     print "Key" ,k,"has" , len(v), "items"

Key 0 has 2 items
Key 1 has 3 items
Key 2 has 3 items
Key 3 has 3 items
Key 4 has 3 items
Key 5 has 2 items
```

EDIT to loop in reverse:

```
reverse = df.reindex(index=df.index[::-1]) 
revSorted = {} 
for i, e in reverse.iterrows(): 
    revSorted[i] = reverse[ (reverse['Time'] > e['Time']-pd.Timedelta('4 hours')) & (reverse['Time'] < e['Time'] + pd.Timedelta('4 hours'))]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I was wondering if it were possible to iterate in reverse? That is, start from the bottom row first and finish with the first row.

Comment: You would have to sort the df.sort_values(["Time"'], ascending=[False]) before using iterrows.

Comment: So this code allows me to loop through the dataframe rows in reverse?


`reverse = pd.reindex(index=pd.index[::-1])`


`revSorted = {}`


`for i, e in reverse.iterrows():
    revSorted[i] = reverse[ (reverse['Time'] > e['Time']-pd.Timedelta('60 seconds')) &
                       (reverse['Time'] < e['Time'] + pd.Timedelta('60 seconds'))]`

Answer (score 1):

The logic for the loop is:

```
df = []
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    df.append([row])
    try:
        for next_row in rows[i + 1:]:
            if abs(row['Time'] - next_row['Time']) < timedelta(hours=4):
                df[i].append(next_row)
            else:
                break
    except IndexError:
        continue
```